# Why JavaScript returns different time when we use TimeZone vs + sign in the String

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to parse a string date time to a JavaScript Date object.
I'm wondering why using `+Number` in the string gives me different result from using `(TimeZome)`

Example:

```
let a = new Date('Nov 01, 2022 09:00:00 +0900')
let b = new Date('2022-11-01T09:00:00.000+09:00')
let c = new Date('01 Nov 2022 09:00:00 (JST)')
let d = new Date('Nov 01, 2022 09:00:00 (JST)')

console.log(`${a.getTime()}    ${a.toISOString()}   ${a.toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZone: 'JST' })}`);
console.log(`${b.getTime()}    ${b.toISOString()}   ${b.toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZone: 'JST' })}`);
console.log(`${c.getTime()}    ${c.toISOString()}   ${c.toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZone: 'JST' })}`);
console.log(`${d.getTime()}    ${d.toISOString()}   ${d.toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZone: 'JST' })}`);
```

the result is

```
"1667260800000    2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z   11/1/2022, 9:00:00 AM"
"1667260800000    2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z   11/1/2022, 9:00:00 AM"
"1667318400000    2022-11-01T16:00:00.000Z   11/2/2022, 1:00:00 AM"
"1667318400000    2022-11-01T16:00:00.000Z   11/2/2022, 1:00:00 AM"
```

it looks like using `(JST)` does not generate the correct result!

Note: I get the same result when I use `Date.parse`

Comment: yes, the browser doesn't seem to recognize `(JST)` ---- if you're using the default date parser, you should really be providing an ISO 8601 compliant date string

Comment: @skara9 the funny part is browser does not throw error

Comment: That's pretty common in native JS methods. `parseInt` will return a valid result from `123abc`. Garbage at the end of the input is simply ignored.

Comment: Please check out -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse  specifically, bit like -> `This section contains implementation-specific behavior that can be inconsistent across implementations.`,   IOW: Date parsing in Javascript is very limited.

Comment: @DaNeSh—where the Date constructor is called with a single string value, it's parsed as for [*Date.parse*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse). The closest that algorithm gets to throwing an error is to return *NaN* if it can't parse the string to a valid [*time value*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range). If the string doesn't conform to one of the two formats supported by ECMA-262, then parsing is implementation dependent (per [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)).